# Returning a True statement if number is 3 and sum contains 3

Tags: python, function, contains

```py
def working_with_three(num1, num2):
    if num1 or num2 == 3 and 3 in str(num1 + num2):
        return True
    else:
        return False

working_with_three(-6, 19)
```

I am trying to create a function that returns True only if one of the numbers is 3 AND the sum contains 3, but when I run this I keep getting True, even though I should be getting False

Comment: This is a very common question (so perhaps should be closed as a duplicate) but not easy to search for. You really want `num1==3 or num2==3` since all `and` and `or` do is link together different things that can be true or false.

Comment: ```3 in str(num1 + num2)``` will give you an error. You are checking for the presence of an ```int``` in a ```str```. Use ```'3' in str(num1 + num2)```.

Comment: Also: Since you convert `num1 + num2` to a string, you must check whether `'3'` is contained in this string, not the integer `3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def working_with_three(num1, num2):
sum1 = num1+num2
if ((num1 ==3 or num2==3) and str(3) in str(sum1)):
    return True
return False
```

Comment: Thank you all for you insights. Especially on the beginner's issues highlighted. This notes will serve me very well going for. The issue is now resolved.

Comment: @SifisoMabaso I think you probably meant this comment on a different answer... You should at least up-vote, and, if you have enough reputation, select an answer!

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a number of interesting "beginners'" issues here.

First  `num1 or num2 == 3` is evaluated as `(num1) or (num2==3)` and then we have to figure out how to convert `(num1)` into something that is true or false. It so happens that in python, the number 0 is false, and all other numbers are true.

So what you really want is `num1==3 or num2==3`.

You also need to think about the other part of the `if`: you want to check whether the *character* "3" is in the string you made from the number, not whether the *number* 3 is in the string (which doesn't even really make sense). So `'3' in str(num1 + num2)`.

But wait, there's more. Whenever you see the pattern

```py
if something:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

you should think deeply about what's happening: `something` is turning out to be `True` or `False` and the routine is then returning `True` or `False`. Which means you can instead just do

```py
return something
```

Comment: To make `return something` equivalent to the `if` statement, you would need to write `return bool(something)` to capture its ["truthiness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false).

Comment: Well, it depends on whether the point of the routine is really to return a bool or just something with that "truthiness" -- and in this case, of course, it actually is a bool.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that the assertion "…you can instead just do" is incorrect.